# Solving a complex number inequality involving absolute values.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Here is the relevant paragraph (from "Complex numbers from A to Z" by Titu Andreescu and Dorin Andrica) :

[image: kek]

Original question : How does $\left | 1+z \right |=t$ imply $\left | 1-z+z^2 \right |=\sqrt{\left | 7-2t^2 \right |}$?

(I checked for $z=i$ , it seems it is wrong ...)

EDIT: It seems it is indeed wrong. So , how can I prove the inequality?(perhaps even the lower and upper bounds need to be changed)

Comment: You checked, and it's wrong (it's also wrong for $z = -1$; it is correct for $z = 1$ though), what more can we say?

Comment: @DanielFischer hmm , so the rest of the proof is also wrong. That's rare for a olympiad book . Anyway , so I'll edit the question to ask how to solve the inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose the following. As $|z|=1$ we have $z^{-1}=\bar{z}$. Then, defining $x=Re(z)$, you get :
$$|1-z+z^2|=|z| \times |z+z^{-1}-1| = |z+\bar{z}-1|=|2x-1|$$

Moreover, $|1+z|^2=(1+z)(1+\bar{z})=1+|z|^2+z+\bar{z})=2(1+x)$. Hence :
$$|1+z|+|1-z+z^2|=\sqrt{2(1+x)}+|2x-1|:=f(x)$$

For $x\in[-1,\frac{1}{2}]$, $f(x)=1+\sqrt{2(x+1)}-2x$, hence $f'(x)=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(x+1)}}-2 \right)$. This is positive from $x=-1$ to $x=-\frac{7}{8}$ and then negative till $x=\frac{1}{2}$.

Then, for $x\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$, $f(x)=\sqrt{2(x+1)}+2x-1$, so $f$ is increasing.

Thus, we have $min(f(-1),f(\frac{1}{2})) \leq f(x) \leq max\left(f(-\frac{7}{8}),f(1)\right)$. Yet $f(-1)=3$, $f(1)=3$.

Yet, $f(-1)=f(1)=3$, $f(\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{3}$ and $f(-\frac{7}{8})=\frac{13}{4}$.

So $\boxed{\sqrt{3} \leq |1+z|+|1-z+z^2| \leq \frac{13}{4}}$, which is not at all the wanted results. ^^ I'm going to do some numeric tests.

**Edit :** so, after a few test with mathematica, if we take $z=\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ (corresponding to my minimum $x=\frac{1}{2}$), we have indeed the value $\sqrt{3}$, which is smaller than $\sqrt{7/2}$, so I guess there is a problem in the exercise.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. Answer in the book is definitely wrong. I'll contact the author. Anyway , how would you approach the problem if abs(z) were not equal to 1? Would that require 2 variables?

Comment: If abs(z) is not 1, then yes, I'm afraid you'll have to use 2 variables. Moreover, the trick $1+z^2-z=z(z+\bar{z}-1)$ won't work anymore, as $\bar{z}\neq z^{-1}$. So I guess the expression you'll have to minimize will be a bit messy.

However, if you don't make any assumptions on $z$, it is clear that you're expression would not have a majorant, so you would only have to determine a minorant.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|z|$, we can write $$ z= \cos\theta+ \sin\theta$$

Now we can derive useful properties for such $z$:

$1+z = 1 + \cos\theta + i\sin\theta = 1 + 2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2} - 1  + 2i\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2} = 2\cos\frac{\theta}{2}(\cos\frac{\theta}{2} + i \sin\frac{\theta}{2})$

Thus, $|1+z| = 2|\cos\frac{\theta}{2}|$. Besides,

$$1 + z^2-z = 1 + \cos2\theta+ i\sin2\theta - (\cos\theta + i\sin\theta) = $$

$$2\cos\theta(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta) - (\cos\theta + i\sin\theta) = (2\cos\theta-1)(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)  $$

Then,

$$| 1 -z + z^2| = |2\cos\theta -1| = \left|4\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2} -3 \right| $$

If you define $x=\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$, with $x \in [-1,1]$, then we have:

$$|1+ z|+ |1 - z + z^2| = 2|x| + |4x^2 -3| = f(x)$$

Whose graph is easy to draw. Just divide the interval of $x$ in pieces such that the expressions inside the modules have constant sign.  To make it easier, note that $f(x)$ is even. Therefore, you can do:

$$x \in \left[0,\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\right] \Rightarrow f(x) = -4x^2 +2x +3$$ 
$$x \in \left[\frac{\sqrt3}{2},1 \right] \Rightarrow f(x) = 4x^2 +2x -3$$

Which gives $f(-\frac{1}{4})=\frac{13}{4}$ for the maximum and $f(\frac{\sqrt3}{2}) = \sqrt3$ for the minimum.